# Orden ejecución eventos GX y JS

Tags: javascript, genexus

Estoy trabajando en GENEXUS X EVO3 con .NET y quería saber como hacer para ejecutar, desde un botón o imagen en un WEBPanel, 2 eventos gx y 1 funcion JavaScript, en el siguiente orden:

> 1. Evento1 GX
> 2. Funcion JS (en textblock HTML)
> 3. Evento2 GX

Consideren que al incluir código JS en codigo GX, éste código JS, siempre se ejecuta el último (luego de todas las sentencias GX). Por ejemplo si se escribe:

```
Event 'Numero1'
   //Sentencia GX1
   //Funcion JS
   //Sentencia GX2
EndEvent
```

Se ejecuta en este orden:

```
Event 'Numero1'
   //Sentencia GX1
   //Sentencia GX2
   //Funcion JS
EndEvent
```

Concretamente lo necesito para lo siguiente:

```
Event 'Numero1'
   //Sentencia GX1: se genera una cadena para un codigoQR
   //Funcion JS: genera offline el codigoQR (mediante Qrious.js)
   //Sentencia GX2: llama un reporte para imprimir el codigoQR

EndEvent
```

Se puede usar JSEvent para asociarlo a un boton o imagen, y ejecutar codigo JS, **ANTES** que sentencias de un evento GX de ese mismo boton, pero ahora me surge el problema que origina esta consulta.
OJALA PUEDEN AYUDARME.
**Muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 0):

Como no obtuve respuesta, considero que es muy probable que no se pueda hacer la ejecución en el orden que necesito. De todas formas, pude encontrar la solución a mi problema, empleando un External Object que genera el código qr mediante una dll por lo que **no se requiere** conexión a intenet (un requisito indispensable en mi problema). El External Object  se puede descargar de:

https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?qrcodegenerator,es

Saludos.